# Restkit mapping objects to NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I have an object that consists of some fields such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               body;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSArray*                imageUrls;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               postId;
@property (nonatomic)           CLLocationCoordinate2D  location;
@property (nonatomic)           LTUser                  *user;
@property (nonatomic)           LTPlace                 *place;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSArray*                comments;
```

All `NSString` and custom objects (such as `LTUser`/`LTPlace`) and it is mapping well.

But, how can I map to the `NSArray` of (`imageUrls` - which is an array of `NSString` / `comments` - which is an array of custom objects (`LTComment`))?

```
"images": [
        "http://****.com/images/1385929903887.jpg",
        "http://****.com/images/131315313131.jpg",
        "http://****.com/images/1351351351.jpg"
]
```

---

Mapping for main object:

```
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LTUser class]];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"_id":@"userId",
                                                  @"username":@"userName",
                                                  @"name":@"name"
                                                  }];   

RKObjectMapping *placeMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LTPlace class]];
[placeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"_id":@"placeId",
                                                   @"image":@"name",
                                                   @"name":@"image"
                                                   }];
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LTPost class]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"_id" : @"postId",
                                              @"createdAt" : @"createdAt",
                                              @"body" : @"body",
                                              @"title" : @"title"
                                              }];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userMapping]];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"place" toKeyPath:@"place" withMapping:placeMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:kLTAPIGetPostsRequest
                                                                                       keyPath:@"posts"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

---

LTComment mapping

```
RKObjectMapping* commentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LTComment class]];
[commentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"user_name":@"userName",
                                                     @"text":@"text"
                                                     }];
```

Comment: Show your current mapping. And the source JSON. Do you have a mapping for `LTComment` already?

Comment: Added description after "Mapping for main object:"

Comment: Added LTComment mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping for `comments` should be just like you mappings for `user` and `place` (just with a different mapping obviously, `commentMapping`). RestKit will determine that the destination is a collection and that the source is a collection and do the right thing.

For `imageUrls`, the JSON is already an array of strings so RestKit can basically copy it. All you need to do is add to the 'container' mapping (whichever that one is):

```
@"images" : @"imageUrls"
```